# React-leaflet update markers position and icon optimization

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet, markers

I am using React 17.0.2 with leaflet 3.1.0 and I have quite a problem regarding markers position on the map and the update of their icon.

In particular I am using server-sent events to retrieve data, which arrives in a very short span of time. This is the code of my  component:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

// ** Store & Actions
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { vehicleDataGlobal, locationDataGlobal } from '../redux/actions/map'

// ** Auth
import useJwt from '../auth/useJwt'

// ** Third Party Components
import L from 'leaflet'
import { Marker } from 'react-leaflet'

// ** Utils
import { isUserLoggedIn } from '../utility/Utils'

import vehicleMarkerImport from '../assets/images/vehicleMarker.svg'
import vehicleMarkerStopImport from '../assets/images/vehicleMarkerStop.svg'

import serviceMarkerImport from '../assets/images/serviceMarker.svg'
import serviceMarkerStopImport from '../assets/images/serviceMarkerStop.svg'

import classes from './Markers.module.css'

// ** Vars
let vehicleData = {}
let locationData = {}
let temporaryMarkerArray = []

const Markers = () => {
 
  // ** State
  const [uid, setUid] = useState('')
  const [markerArray, setMarkerArray] = useState([])

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true
    useJwt
    .getFactionData()
    .then(res => {
      if (mounted) {
        if (typeof res.data !== 'undefined' && res.data !== null && Array.isArray(res.data)) {
          setUid(res.data[0].uid)
        } 
      }
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('Something went wrong with getFactionData():', err))
    return function cleanup() {
      mounted = false
    }
  }, [])
 
  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true
    if (uid) {
      useJwt
      .getRealtimeData(uid)
      .then(res => {
        if (mounted) {
          if (typeof res.data !== 'undefined' && res.data !== null && Array.isArray(res.data)) {
            for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
              if (typeof res.data[i] !== 'undefined' && res.data[i] !== null) {
                vehicleData[res.data[i].imei] = res.data[i]
              }
            }
            dispatch(vehicleDataGlobal(vehicleData))
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('Something went wrong with getRealtimeData():', err))
      return function cleanup() {
        mounted = false
      }
    }
  }, [uid, dispatch])   

  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true
   
    const addMarkerToMap = data => {
      if (data.gpsData !== null) {
        const raceNumber = vehicleData[data.imei].raceNumber
        const latitude = data.gpsData.coordsWgs84.lat
        const longitude = data.gpsData.coordsWgs84.lng 
        const azimuth = data.gpsData.azimuth
        const speed = data.gpsData.speed
        const imei = data.imei
        let index = null
        let hit = false
        for (let i = 0; i < temporaryMarkerArray.length; i++) {
          if (temporaryMarkerArray[i].raceNumber === raceNumber) {
            index = i
            hit = true
          }
        }
        if (latitude !== null && longitude !== null && azimuth !== null && speed !== null) {
          if (hit === false) {
            addNewMarkerToMap(raceNumber, latitude, longitude, azimuth, speed, imei)
          } else {
            updateExistingMarker(raceNumber, latitude, longitude, azimuth, speed, imei, index)
          }
        }
      }
    }

    const updateExistingMarker = (raceNumber, latitude, longitude, azimuth, speed, imei, index) => {
      let markerHTML = ''
      temporaryMarkerArray[index].position = [latitude, longitude]
      temporaryMarkerArray[index].azimuth = azimuth
      temporaryMarkerArray[index].speed = speed
      if (raceNumber.length <= 3) {
        if (speed === 0) {
          markerHTML = `<div class=${classes.markerDiv} id=${imei}><img src=${vehicleMarkerStopImport} alt="vehicle marker icon" style="transform: rotate(0deg)"/><p class=${classes.markerLabel}>${raceNumber}</p></div>`
        } else {
          markerHTML = `<div class=${classes.markerDiv} id=${imei}><img src=${vehicleMarkerImport} alt="vehicle marker icon" style="transform: rotate(${azimuth}deg)"/><p class=${classes.markerLabel}>${raceNumber}</p></div>`
        }
      } else {
        if (speed === 0) {
          markerHTML = `<div class=${classes.markerDiv} id=${imei}><img src=${serviceMarkerStopImport} alt="service marker icon" style="transform: rotate(0deg)"/><p class=${classes.markerLabel}>${raceNumber}</p></div>`
        } else {
          markerHTML = `<div class=${classes.markerDiv} id=${imei}><img src=${serviceMarkerImport} alt="service marker icon" style="transform: rotate(${azimuth}deg)"/><p class=${classes.markerLabel}>${raceNumber}</p></div>`
        }
      }
      const markerIcon = new L.divIcon({
        className: 'markerIcon',
        html: markerHTML,
        iconSize: [32, 32],
        iconAnchor: [16, 16]
      })
      if (temporaryMarkerArray[index].icon.options.html !== markerHTML) {
        temporaryMarkerArray[index].icon = markerIcon
      }
    }

    const source = useJwt.connectSSE()
    source.onmessage = res => {
      if (mounted === true) {
        if (isUserLoggedIn() === false) {
          source.close()
        } else {
          const payloadSSE = JSON.parse(res.data)
          if (typeof payloadSSE !== 'undefined' && payloadSSE !== null) {
            if (Array.isArray(payloadSSE)) {
              for (let i = 0; i < payloadSSE.length; i++) {
                if (typeof payloadSSE[i] !== 'undefined' && payloadSSE[i] !== null) {
                  locationData[payloadSSE[i].imei] = payloadSSE[i]
                  if (typeof vehicleData[payloadSSE[i].imei] !== 'undefined') {
                    addMarkerToMap(payloadSSE[i])
                  }
                }
              }
            } else {
              if (typeof payloadSSE.aliveTs === 'undefined') {
                locationData[payloadSSE.imei] = payloadSSE
                if (typeof vehicleData[payloadSSE.imei] !== 'undefined') {
                  addMarkerToMap(payloadSSE)
                }
              } else {
                console.log(payloadSSE)
              }
            }
            dispatch(locationDataGlobal(locationData))
            setMarkerArray([...temporaryMarkerArray])
          }
        }
      } 
    }

    return function cleanup() {
      mounted = false
    }
  }, [dispatch])

  const addNewMarkerToMap = (raceNumber, latitude, longitude, azimuth, speed, imei) => {
    let markerHTML = ''
    if (raceNumber.length <= 3) {
      if (speed !== 0) {
        markerHTML = `<div class=${classes.markerDiv} id=${imei}><img src=${vehicleMarkerImport} alt="vehicle marker icon" style="transform: rotate(${azimuth}deg)"/><p class=${classes.markerLabel}>${raceNumber}</p></div>`
      } else {
        markerHTML = `<div class=${classes.markerDiv} id=${imei}><img src=${vehicleMarkerStopImport} alt="vehicle marker icon"/><p class=${classes.markerLabel}>${raceNumber}</p></div>`
      } 
    } else {
      if (speed !== 0) {
        markerHTML = `<div class=${classes.markerDiv} id=${imei}><img src=${serviceMarkerImport} alt="service marker icon" style="transform: rotate(${azimuth}deg)"/><p class=${classes.markerLabel}>${raceNumber}</p></div>`
      } else (speed === 0) {
        markerHTML = `<div class=${classes.markerDiv} id=${imei}><img src=${serviceMarkerStopImport} alt="service marker icon"/><p class=${classes.markerLabel}>${raceNumber}</p></div>`
      }
    }
    const markerIcon = new L.divIcon({
      html: markerHTML,
      iconSize: [32, 32],
      iconAnchor: [16, 16]
    })
    temporaryMarkerArray.push({
      icon: markerIcon,
      position: [latitude, longitude],
      raceNumber: raceNumber,
      imei: imei,
      azimuth: azimuth,
      speed: speed,
    })
  }

  return (
    markerArray.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <Marker 
          key={item.raceNumber}
          icon={item.icon}
          position={item.position}
          raceNumber={item.raceNumber}
          azimuth={item.azimuth}
          speed={item.speed}
        />
      )
    })
  )
}

export default Markers
```

The code above does work (positions and icons are updated correctly) but it is incredibly slow, especially if dispatch is used. Moreover it freezes completely if F12 is pressed in order to inspect it.

I am quite new to React so I was wondering if there is a way to optimize/rewrite it and if there is a way to update icons without create a new one every time.

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

The problem regarding markers position on the map has been solved by completely rewriting the code, adding Custom Hooks and using Context.

I still wonder if there is a way to update the icons without creating a new one every time.

Comment: How many markers are you theoretically handling at one time?

Comment: At the moment around 300 but the application should handle at least 600 markers at one time.

Comment: It's possible that you are registering the onmessage handler each time useEffect is run `const source = useJwt.connectSSE(); source.onmessage = res => {`. This would cause source.onmessage to execute multiple times causing multiple re-rendinerings when a `dispatch` is called

Comment: @teddybeard you are right. The code above would start and then close the connection to the SSE at each render. To avoid this I have created a custom hook. So, while this behaviour has been corrected, the dispatch method is still giving me problems...